# Make Drive resources available to all users in organization

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing

My company uses G Suite Basic. I have a handful of company resources that I'd like to make visible and available to everyone in the company via their Drive - things like employee handbook, benefits resources, etc.

So I'd like a new employee (a newly added G Suite user) to visit their Drive for the first time and have these documents already sitting there in their Drive waiting for them. This happened to me when I was an employee with a previous employer, and it was great, but I've been unable to figure it out with my own G Suite account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an existing option on the G Suite account yet. You can share the files but the user will have to go to "Shared with me" to find them, on the other side if you have knowledge about Apps Script or Google Drive API you can create script that make a copy of those files, rename them and then change ownership to the new user, by doing this the new folder will appear on the Google Drive of that specific new user.

Here are some reference links you can use.

*Google Drive API*

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/

*Apps Script*

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/